# Speech recognition: microphone working in software but not in Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3

I am using an external sound card with a built-in microphone for voice recognition on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B. The issue is that when I run the code the code executes but then stops on "SAY SOMETHING". When I terminate the code I get these errors.

This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as voice

def voice_recognition():

    speech = voice.Recognizer()

    with voice.Microphone() as source:

        print("SAY SOMETHING")

        audio = speech.listen(source)

    try:    

        command = speech.recognize_google(audio)

        check = "forward" in command

        check1 = "backward" in command    

        if(check == True):

            print ('1')

        if(check1 == True):

            print ('2')

        else:

            print ('3')

    except:

        pass

voice_recognition()
```

## And I am getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/voice.py", line 29, in <module>
    voice_recognition()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/voice.py", line 9, in voice_recognition
    audio = speech.listen(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 
620, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 
161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "errors" that you're seeing are normal when you terminate a Python program. If you run any Python code and terminate it (by pressing Ctrl+C on the command line) before it finishes, you will see a traceback of where the code terminated.

---

According to the [speech_recognition library reference](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst), `Recognizer.listen()` will not use a timeout by default (you can use `listen(timeout=20)` to timeout if nothing is received in 20 seconds). The code is probably using a wrong microphone, so the library never receives audio, so the program never terminates.

You should be able to use `Microphone.list_microphone_names()` to get a list of available microphones, and pass the index of your external microphone to the constructor (e.g. `Microphone(device_index=3)`).